# ChartDirector: customize candlestick shadow color on finance chart

Tags: c#, .net, charts, candlestick-chart

Per **[this link](http://www.chartdir.com/forum/download_thread.php?site=chartdir&bn=chartdir_support&thread=1377860515#N1379315001)**, I am trying to create a finance candlestick chart in [ChartDirector](http://www.advsofteng.com/product.html) using the following code in C#/.NET 4.0:

```
FinanceChart c = new FinanceChart(760);
...
CandleStickLayer cLayer = c.addCandleStick(0x00FF00, 0xFF0000);
cLayer.getDataSet(0).setDataColor(0x00FF00, 0x00FF00);
cLayer.getDataSet(1).setDataColor(0xFF0000, 0xFF0000);
```

But the result I get is similar to the question on the support forum, since my green candles (for up) have red borders, and my red candlesticks (for down) have green shadows. As per the link in the original question, I am also trying to draw a chart similar to [this one](http://www.bseindia.com/charting/BSETechnicalCharts.aspx?SYMBOL=500111), which contains red candles with red edge colors and red shadows, and green candles that are similarly all green.

The documentation for CandleStickLayer is [here](http://www.advsofteng.com/doc/cdnet.htm#XYChart.addCandleStickLayer.htm) and the documentation for setDataColor is [here](http://www.advsofteng.com/doc/cdnet.htm#DataSet.setDataColor.htm).

I don't know what's going wrong - please help!

Answer (score 0):

The code should be:

```
CandleStickLayer cLayer = c.addCandleStick(0x00EE00, 0xE65C01);
cLayer.getDataSet(0).setDataColor(0x00EE00, Chart.SameAsMainColor);
cLayer.getDataSet(1).setDataColor(0xE65C01, Chart.SameAsMainColor);
```

in order to draw a chart with candles that have the same color borders and shadows as the main body.